# Facebook recycles likes activity

Tags: facebook

So I click "like" on all kinds of things. Religious, political etc. Just because I like something does not mean that I agree with it. I am simple interested in learning about it.

So I clicked "like" on a specific religious organization about two months ago. Since then I have clicked like on over 200 other things. Probably at least 50 other organizations. Rough estimate.

I sign in to my Facebook and "bam!" my friends are asking me if I belong to this organization. I have to tell them no. I was simply interested in learning about it and talking to them. I like things about them but I do not belong to it or want to promote it.

So my friends inform me that they are being told that I like this organization and that I clicked on. Why would this be happening if I clicked like on it so long ago? This makes me mad. It seems like the organization has priority over all the other recent companies I clicked like on. To me that is unfair, and unjust and sounds like collusion.

Does Facebook take money from organizations to promote to others through"like button clicks?

Will unclicking to share "likes and notifications" actually make a difference? The reason people like me have to keep asking this same question is because we just don't trust Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

If you "like" something, it will not disappear over time unless you "unlike".

What seems to be occurring is that the organization is using sponsored stories. Based on the setup, sponsored stories place a friend who likes the page immediately above the story. This makes it unclear whether you like the promoted post or just the page.

Consider adding the organization page to an "interest" list, that way you can get the feed without explicitly liking the page.

Answer (score 1):

"Does Facebook take money from organizations to promote to others through"like button clicks?"

Yes, that is one of the features of Facebook advertising.